# Numpy loadtext says my file doesn't exist (it does exist though)

Tags: python, file, numpy, printing

Complete beginner. I'm just trying to print the numbers in a text file called 'sample'.

Here is what the file looks like:

```
5 10
6 12
8 15
4 8
```

my code:

```
import numpy as np

data = np.loadtxt("sample.txt")

print data
```

I keep getting back this error:

```
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'sample.txt'
```

The same thing happens when i just say "sample". And this python script and sample.txt are both in the same folder (Documents)

Comment: Are you sure that python is running in the same directory as where your file is located?

Comment: well the python file i'm working with and sample.txt are in teh same documents folder. Do you mean the python program as a whole? I doubt it - do i have to write out the whole path to my sample.txt in my code?

Comment: I'm using Canopy, and that along with Python 3.4 are in my Applications folder.

Comment: I believe that python uses as working directory the one from which it is launched, this might depend on if you launch it via a windows shortcut or from the command line. In your script do `import os; print(os.getcwd())` to see where it is running. You could also try to load your sample file using the full path name.

Comment: okay the os command printed this back: %run /Users/ben/Documents/test2.py
/Users/ben ***note /users/ben is on a new line, so does that mean I'm just running from users/ben?

Comment: it worked! i just put the full path name -FINALLY HAHA

Comment: thanks for putting up with my beginner Q's Bas. Is there a command i could put to go to a certain directory, so I dont' have to type the full path?

Comment: nevermind. i figured it out. just used os.chdir

Comment: If you found a solution that worked, you should answer the question and then accept your answer

Comment: i can't answer my question for 8 hours because im' new